# Error when packaging selenium with py2exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, py2exe, python-importlib

I am using a python 3.4 environment in Anaconda 4.3, and I'm attempting to use py2exe to package a python script that uses selenium.  The script runs perfectly as a .py file, but the .exe is returning an error when attempting to import the webdriver from the selenium module with the import statement:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

This is the traceback returned in the console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 40, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .webelement import WebElement
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 40, in <module>
    getAttribute_js = pkgutil.get_data(__package__, 'getAttribute.js').decode('utf8')
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py34\lib\pkgutil.py", line 611, in get_data
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(package)
  File "C:\Users\me\.conda\envs\py34\lib\importlib\util.py", line 81, in find_spec
    fullname = resolve_name(name, package) if name.startswith('.') else name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Edited to phrase this as an actual question:  This import statement works fine when running the file as a .py script. Why would this only happen after being packaged by py2exe, and is there some kind of option I am missing in the py2exe setup file?

Comment: And what is the question? Show what is the `resolve_name`. How do you define it?

Comment: @Andersson I suppose the question is, what exactly is going wrong here?  I did not define `resolve_name`, it is a function in the standard python library that is being called by the python interpreter. The only thing I defined was the import statement I stated above (It's the code that is being called in the traceback `File "my_script.py", line 8, in <module>`

I followed each of these files in the traceback and still am not sure why a `NoneType` is being passed to the `resolve_name` function, when it appears it should be the `.webelement` package.  I'm not sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: Oh.. yep, I paid not enough attention to logs... If you use IDE like `PyCharm` you can simply trace what is the `name` (CTRL + left click on `name`) argument that should be passed to `resolve_name`. It's a bad idea, but if interpreter has problems with defining `name` you can try to hardcode `name` value in `util.py` before convertion into `.exe` and then return back `util.py` to default state

Comment: @MorningSpider, I am facing same problem. Did you resolved your problem?

Comment: @pratibha Unfortunately, I was unable to resolve the issue, and I ultimately scrapped the whole project for unrelated reasons.